# i want to change the title of the Tabbed Child Activity in android

Tags: android, titlebar, android-titlebar, android-tabbed-activity, tabbed-view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The above is the code which is in the actitvity_main2.xml which is the child activity of activity_main.xml.

I want to change the title of this child activity when I pass from Main activity to Main2Acitivty. This is the picture which has the title of the main application(i.e. Stocks).

[image: This is the picture which has the title of the main application(i.e. Stocks)]

I want to change the title to something else when Main2Activity(this activity contains Tabbed views as you can see in the image) is loaded. I tried to use `getActionBar().setTitle(<name to put on title>);` and also used `setTitle(<name to put in the title>)` but nothing worked.

Please help as I am new to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make Style in sytle.xml file**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Call below code from your first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("TitleBarName","FirstActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

**On SecondActivity**

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    String titleName = getIntent().getStringExtra("TitleBarName");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titleName);
```

and make sure to check in manifest file.

if you use toolbar then you have to put this theme in that activity in manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot man it finally worked. You the only one who could solve it. @chetanPatel

Answer (score 0):

I am giving all code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);         

// This listener helps for changing name on title when you change page through slide or click on tab
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if(adapter != null){
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(adapter.getPageTitle(position));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }    

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TabOne(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabSecond(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabThird(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.taxsmart.testapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Add Dependencies in gradle file**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

**There are three tab that is fragment. All fragment's xml file**

**tabone.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TabOne"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**tabsecond.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TabSecond"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**tabthird.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TabThird"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**All Fragment java file**
**TabOne.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabOne extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabone, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**TabSecond.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class TabSecond extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabsecond, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**TabThird.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabThird extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabthird, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**I hope this will resolve your issue.**

Comment: I want to change the title which is an already fetched string @chetanpatel

Comment: consider that I already have one value than what should I do to change the title of the toolbar to that value? @Chetan

Comment: @webcode please clear me your doubt. You want to set title in toolbar, and title will be the tab title, correct?

Comment: no, I have a value which is sent from the MainActivity to the Main2Activity(this activity has the tabs, in your example the MainActivity has tabs). And when Main2Activity is loaded I want to set the value obtained from MainActivity to the toolbar of Main2Activity. @chetan patel